# How to use Java to compare two csv files?

Tags: java, csv

So this is what I am trying to do is to make a backup file for an oracle sql table. I used opencsv.jar to create table_bkup.csv file.

I am then supposed to compare 3 columns in the backup file to the current table on the oracle database.

I've decided to have it make another csv as table_current.csv file.

I now want to compare the two csv files to see if the 3 columns have increased or decreased.  There are 58 rows of data and 20 columns in the table.

Now the values in the three columns are always supposed to be equal to backup or increase in value.
If there is an issue and a value decreases it needs to send an email to a supervisor.

How would I do this?
Thank you,
Michael B.

P.S. I am fairly new to Java programming, and any help would be appreciated!  I've spent about 11 hours on this project so far including all the research and learning how to accomplish as much as I have.

Comment: I guess you'd start with some tutorials on Java?  You want to read a text (CSV) file, parse values from it, compare those values, send an email... All things that have examples online.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow so this took forever to do, but it works yay!
End result:

```
    try{
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("b2b_control_number_bkup.csv"));
         String [] nextLine;

         int counter = 0;

         // First File Variables
         String SENDER_NAME = null;
         String RECEIVER_NAME = null;
         String DOC_PROTOCOL_NAME = null;
         String DIRECTION = null;
         String NAME = null;
         String IS_DEFAULT = null;
         /*
         String INTERCHANGE = null;
         String GROUP_NUM  = null;
         String TRANSACTION_NUM = null;
         */
         int INTERCHANGE = 0;
         int GROUP_NUM  = 0;
         int TRANSACTION_NUM = 0;

         //Second File variables
         String SENDER_NAMEb = null;
         String RECEIVER_NAMEb = null;
         String DOC_PROTOCOL_NAMEb = null;
         String DIRECTIONb = null;
         String NAMEb = null;
         String IS_DEFAULTb = null;
         /*
         String INTERCHANGEb = null;
         String GROUP_NUMb  = null;
         String TRANSACTION_NUMb = null;
         */
         int INTERCHANGEb = 0;
         int GROUP_NUMb  = 0;
         int TRANSACTION_NUMb = 0;

         while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
             //System.out.println(nextLine[4] +" "+ nextLine[5] +" "+ nextLine[6]);
             SENDER_NAME = nextLine[0];
             RECEIVER_NAME = nextLine[1];
             DOC_PROTOCOL_NAME = nextLine[2];
             DIRECTION = nextLine[3];

             INTERCHANGE = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[4]);
             GROUP_NUM  = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[5]);
             TRANSACTION_NUM = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[6]);

             NAME = nextLine[15];
             IS_DEFAULT = nextLine[16];


             // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line

             CSVReader readerb = new CSVReader(new FileReader("b2b_control_number_current.csv"));
             String [] nextLineb;

             while ((nextLineb = readerb.readNext()) != null) {
                 SENDER_NAMEb = nextLineb[0];
                 RECEIVER_NAMEb = nextLineb[1];
                 DOC_PROTOCOL_NAMEb = nextLineb[2];
                 DIRECTIONb = nextLineb[3];

                 INTERCHANGEb = Integer.parseInt(nextLineb[4]);
                 GROUP_NUMb  = Integer.parseInt(nextLineb[5]);
                 TRANSACTION_NUMb = Integer.parseInt(nextLineb[6]);

                 NAMEb = nextLineb[15];
                 IS_DEFAULTb = nextLineb[16];


                 //System.out.println(nextLineb[4] +" "+ nextLineb[5] +" "+ nextLineb[6]);
                 //System.out.println("RECEIVER_NAMEa: " + RECEIVER_NAME +" "+ RECEIVER_NAMEb);
                 if((SENDER_NAME.equals(SENDER_NAMEb))
                         && (RECEIVER_NAME.equals(RECEIVER_NAMEb)) 
                         && (DOC_PROTOCOL_NAME.equals(DOC_PROTOCOL_NAMEb)) 
                         && (DIRECTION.equals(DIRECTIONb)) 
                         && (NAME.equals(NAMEb)) 
                         && (IS_DEFAULT.equals(IS_DEFAULTb))){
                     if((INTERCHANGE<=(INTERCHANGEb)) && (GROUP_NUM<=(GROUP_NUMb)) && (TRANSACTION_NUM<=(TRANSACTION_NUMb))){
                         pw.println("Everything Okay");
                     }else{
                         pw.println("Error Send Email");
                         sendEmail ="1";
                       }


                     //System.out.println("RECEIVER_NAME: " + RECEIVER_NAME +" "+ RECEIVER_NAMEb);
                     pw.println("INTERCHANGE: " + INTERCHANGE +" "+ INTERCHANGEb +
                             "   GROUP_NUM: " + GROUP_NUM +" "+ GROUP_NUMb+ 
                             "   TRANSACTION_NUM: " + TRANSACTION_NUM +" "+ TRANSACTION_NUMb);
                 }
             }
            /*
               counter ++;

             if(counter == 2){
             break;
             }
             */
             readerb.close();
         }
         reader.close();
         }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

One method for doing this would be to use java's [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface; read each line as a string, add it to the set, then do a [`removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) with the second set on the first set, thus retaining the rows which differ. This, of course, assumes that there are no duplicate rows in the files.

```
// using FileUtils to read in the files.
HashSet<String> f1 = new HashSet<String>(FileUtils.readLines("file1.csv"));
HashSet<String> f2 = new HashSet<String>(FileUtils.readLines("file2.csv"));
f1.removeAll(f2); // f1 now contains only the lines which are not in f2
```

You have a PK field? I'll just assume you know how to get that from your string; use openCSV or regex or whatever you want. Make an actual `HashMap` instead of a `HashSet` as above, use the PK as the key and the row as the value.

```
HashMap<String, String> f1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> f2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
// read f1, f2; use PK field as the key
List<String> deleted = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> updated = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : f1.keySet()) {
    if(!f2.containsKey(entry.getKey()) {
        deleted.add(entry.getValue());
    } else {
        if(!f2.get(entry.getKey().equals(f1.getValue())) {
            updated.add(f1.getValue());
        }
    }
}
for(String key : f1.keySet()) {
    f2.remove(key);
}
// f2 now contains only "new" rows
```